# Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x^2} \int_x^{x + \ln(x)/x} e^{-t^2} dt $

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I've been trying all day to solve this and I can't figure it out how to do it, I know you have to use L'Hopital and that is a similar one to another limit that is already posted here, but the exponential having a minus complicates everything.

I need help, please.

Comment: Hint: $$
e^{ - x^2 }  = \frac{1}{{e^{x^2 } }}.
$$ Now you have a ratio and can apply the L'Hopital rule. Wasn't that complicated after all.

Comment: @Gary there is no point to L'Hopital, this limit ($0\cdot 0$) is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry, I did not read the question correctly. I thought the OP is asked to use L'Hopital.

Comment: Hint: By the monotonicity of the integrand, $$
\left| {\int_x^{x + \ln (x)/x} {e^{ - t^2 } dt} } \right| \le \left( \left(x + \frac{{\ln (x)}}{x}\right) - x\right)e^{ - x^2 }  = \frac{{\ln (x)}}{x}e^{ - x^2 } .
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying the expression.

First, we'll use a limit law, saying the limit of a product is a product of the limits.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{-x^2} \cdot \lim_{x\to\infty} \int^{x+\frac{\ln(x)}{x}}_x e^{-t^2}dt$$

Let's evaluate the first limit.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}$$

As $x$ approaches $\infty$, $e^{x^2}$ also approaches $\infty$, therefore $\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}$ approaches $0$, therefore one of the limits calculated is $0$.

However, we're not done. If the limit of the integral is $\infty$, we would get an indeterminate form. By monotonicity,
$$|{\int_x^{x+\frac{\ln(x)}{x}} e^{-t^2}dt}|\leq (x+\frac{\ln(x)}{x}-x)e^{-x^2}=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}e^{-x^2}$$, which if we evaluate as $x$ approaches $\infty$, we get $0 \cdot 0 =0$, so we didn't have to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Hope this helps!

P.S. Special thanks to Gary for the monotoncity hints!

Comment: You do not need to calculate the integral to conlude, see my comment below the question.

Comment: The problem is that you should **ONLY** apply L'Hôpital's Rule if the limit results in an indeterminate form. Otherwise, you may end up with a different answer.

Comment: I meant the other comment, the last one. By the way, a less known fact is that L'Hôpital's rule works for $\frac{\text{whatever}}{\infty}$ not just $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: That's true! I think I should put that in the answer!

Comment: How about citing me? It was not your idea after all.